# AngularDart ngIf else

Tags: angular-dart

Does Angular**Dart** support else blocks in [`ngIf`](https://pub.dev/documentation/angular/latest/angular/NgIf-class.html)? The best solution I can think of is `ngSwitch`:

```
<div [ngSwitch]="condition">
  <foo *ngSwitchCase="true"/>
  <bar *ngSwitchCase="false"/>
</div>
```

Doesn't seem very elegant though.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not the preferred way but I have been just using two opposite ngif lines.

```
<div *ngIf="condition">
  <foo>
</div>
<div *ngIf="!condition">
  <bar>
</div>
```